# CSV Delimited to XML - Folder Hierarchy

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, doubly-linked-list

This is my first time posting so I apologize for any ignorance or failed use of examples.

I have a console app project to create where I have been given a fair few CSV files and I need to create some kind of Parent/Child/Grandchild relationship out of them (XML? maybe? - then I can use that to do the uploads and writes to the DMS with minimal calls - I don't want to be querying if a folder exists over and over)

I am a little out of my depth on this one

I need to know the best way to do this without 3rd party library dependencies, pure C#, using the OLEDB JET provider is most likely required as it will handle the parsing required, there is no order to the CSV files in regards to date, previous years could appear down the list and vice versa.

Here's an example of the CSV output

```
"DESCRIPTION1","8, 5/8\" X 6.4MM","STRING","filename001.pdf","2016-09-19","1"  
"DESCRIPTION2","12, 3/4\" X 6.4MM","STRING","filename001.pdf","2016-09-19","1"  
"DESCRIPTION3","12, 3/4\" X 6.4MM","STRING","filename001.pdf","2016-09-19","1"  
"another description 20# gw","1","388015","Scan123.pdf","2015-10-24","1"  
"another description 20# gw","3","385902","Scan456.pdf","2015-04-14","1"  
"STRINGVAL1","273.10 X 9.27 X 6000","45032-01","KHJDWNEJWKFD9101529.pdf","2012-02-03","1"  
"STRINGVAL2","273.10 X 21.44 X 6000","7-09372","DJSWH68767681540.pdf","2017-02-03","1"
```

The end output will be (`YEAR/MONTH/FILENAME` + (Attributes for each file - these are for eventually updating columns inside a DMS))

Year and Month retrieved from the column with the date

If the YEAR alread exists then it will not be created again
If the month under that year exists it will not be created again
If the filename already exists under that YEAR/MONTH it will not be created again BUT the additional ATTRIBUTES for that FileName will be added to the attributes - "line seperated?"

Required Output:

[image]

I have attempted a Linq query to begin to output the possible required XML for me to progress but it outputs every row and does no grouping, I am not familiar with Linq at the moment.

I also ran into issues with the basic escaping on the .Split(',') doing it this way (see original CSV examples above compared to me using TAB separation in my test file and example below) which is why I want the Oledb provider to handle it.

```
string[] source = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Processing\In\mockCsv.csv");
XElement item = new XElement("Root",
    from str in source
    let fields = str.Split('\t')
    select new XElement("Year", fields[4].Substring(0, 4),
    new XElement("Month", fields[4].Substring(5, 2),
        new XElement("FileName", fields[3]),
        new XElement("Description",fields[0]),
        new XElement("Length", fields[1]),
        new XElement("Type", fields[2]),
        new XElement("FileName", fields[3]),
        new XElement("Date", fields[4]),
        new XElement("Authorised", fields[5]))
        )                
);
```

I also need to log every step of the process so I have setup a Logger class

```
private class Logger
{
    private static string LogFile = null;

    internal enum MsgType
    {
        Info,
        Debug,
        Error
    }

    static Logger()
    {
        var processingDetails = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(SECTION_PROCESSINGDETAILS) as NameValueCollection;
        LogFile = Path.Combine(processingDetails[KEY_WORKINGFOLDER],
                                String.Format("Log_{0}.txt", StartTime.ToString("MMMyyyy")));
        if (File.Exists(LogFile))
            File.Delete(LogFile);
    }

    internal static void Write(string msg, MsgType msgType, bool isNewLine, bool closeLine)
    {
        if (isNewLine)
            msg = String.Format("{0} - {1} : {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), msgType, msg);

        if (closeLine)
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        else
            Console.Write(msg);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LogFile))
            return;

        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(LogFile, true))
            {
                if (closeLine)
                    sw.WriteLine(msg);
                else
                    sw.Write(msg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Used as such

```
Logger.Write(String.Format("Reading records from csv file ({0})... ",
            csvFile), Logger.MsgType.Info, true, false);
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what is your problem. You can't parse CSV? Or you don't know how to create an xml from objects in memory? Please update a question to make it more specific.

Comment: I am not sure how to group the objects from the csv and then output them into XML in the required distinct format with grouped attributes on top

Comment: Use .Net's `TextFieldParser`. At any rate, you're asking too much in one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following.  If you are reading from a file use StreamReader instead of StringReader :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication74
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                        "\"DESCRIPTION1\",\"8, 5/8 X 6.4MM\",\"STRING\",\"filename001.pdf\",\"2016-09-19\",\"1\"\n" +
                        "\"DESCRIPTION2\",\"12, 3/4 X 6.4MM\",\"STRING\",\"filename001.pdf\",\"2016-09-19\",\"1\"\n" +
                        "\"DESCRIPTION3\",\"12, 3/4 X 6.4MM\",\"STRING\",\"filename001.pdf\",\"2016-09-19\",\"1\"\n" +
                        "\"another description 20# gw\",\"1\",\"388015\",\"Scan123.pdf\",\"2015-10-24\",\"1\"\n" +
                        "\"another description 20# gw\",\"3\",\"385902\",\"Scan456.pdf\",\"2015-04-14\",\"1\"\n" +
                        "\"STRINGVAL1\",\"273.10 X 9.27 X 6000\",\"45032-01\",\"KHJDWNEJWKFD9101529.pdf\",\"2012-02-03\",\"1\"\n" +
                        "\"STRINGVAL2\",\"273.10 X 21.44 X 6000\",\"7-09372\",\"DJSWH68767681540.pdf\",\"2017-02-03\",\"1\"\n";

            string pattern = "\\\"\\s*,\\s*\\\"";

            string inputline = "";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(input);

            XElement root = new XElement("Root");
            while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitLine = Regex.Split(inputline,pattern);
                Item newItem = new Item() {
                    description = splitLine[0].Replace("\"",""),
                    length = splitLine[1],
                    type = splitLine[2],
                    filename = splitLine[3],
                    date = DateTime.Parse(splitLine[4]),
                    authorized = splitLine[5].Replace("\"", "") == "1" ? true : false
                };

                Item.items.Add(newItem);
            }

            foreach(var year in Item.items.GroupBy(x => x.date.Year).OrderBy(x => x.Key))
            {
                XElement newYear = new XElement("_" + year.Key.ToString());
                root.Add(newYear);
                foreach(var month in year.GroupBy(x => x.date.Month).OrderBy(x => x.Key))
                {
                    XElement newMonth = new XElement("_" + month.Key.ToString());
                    newYear.Add(newMonth);

                    newMonth.Add(
                        month.OrderBy(x => x.date).Select(x => new XElement(
                            x.filename,
                            string.Join("\r\n", new object[] {
                                x.description,
                                x.length,
                                x.type,
                                x.date.ToString(),
                                x.authorized.ToString()
                            }).ToList()
                    )));
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public class Item
    {
        public static List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        public string description { get; set; }
        public string length { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public Boolean authorized { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is pretty late here now, I have run it up and viewed the output and I think I can manipulate it slightly to give me something to work with, thank you for your time (I gave you an up-vote but due to my new status it said it was recorded but not shown on the page)

Comment: Answered - I have managed to manipulate it slightly to output an XML structure I can work with, thank you guys heaps